# Does flaming sphere always need a move action to attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

A [Flaming Sphere](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/flamingSphere.html) will 'attack' anyone it rolls into the same square as:

> If it enters a space with a creature, it stops moving for the round and deals 3d6 points of fire damage to that creature, though a successful Reflex save negates that damage.

However if its 'at rest' it doesn't move:

> The sphere moves as long as you actively direct it (a move action for
>   you); otherwise, it merely stays at rest and burns.

However what happens if the sphere rolls into the same square as a target on turn 1 (who rolls their Reflex save as per usual) but said target then doesn't move out of that square?

**Does the mage need to use their move action to attack the target again even though the sphere is still in the square as them?**

Note: The flaming sphere is 5 ft diameter in both [3.5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/flamingSphere.htm) and [Pathfinder](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/flamingSphere.html) and a standard 3.PF square is 5 ft square.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The sphere will remain on the same square until the wizard spends a move action to move it again, or the wizard moves out of the spell's range. 
I quote your quote:

> The sphere moves as long as you actively direct it (a move action for you); otherwise, it merely stays at rest and burns.

That means that while the wizard is inside the spell's range, AND the spell's duration has not expired, the sphere is active regardless if the wizard moves it or not. So if it occupies the same square with a target, and the target does not move out of the square, she will be burned by the sphere, on the wizards next round WITHOUT any action needed by the wizard.

-EDIT-

Flaming sphere's diameter is 5 ft, both in Pathfinder and 3.5.

- [Pathfinder](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/flamingSphere.html/)
- [3.5 RAW](http://d20srd.org/srd/spells/flamingSphere.htm/)

So it is logical that a square occupied by the sphere is on fire for the duration of the spell, and anybody that is on the same square or passes through it is affected by the spell (Entitled to a reflex save or damage) regardless if the caster moves the sphere on her round. Credit to @Can Canbeck and @medivh for the comments clarifications :)

Comment: I still have doubts: by RAW the sphere has not _entered_ a creature's space, so it shouldn't be entitled to deal damage. However... 1) By RAI, it seems logical that it should still deal damage to a creature in this space; but also 2) It seems illogical that the creature does not suffer any additional condition (such as the ones you experience while squeezing) being its square filled by a 5-ft. diameter sphere. How you reconcile 1) with 2)? If you are going to allow one I'm pretty sure you have to allow the other too.

Comment: @Erik 3e wasn't designed like 4e was, to be a complete description of every possible relevant rule. It was built on the assumption (default of all RPGs in 2000) that sensible effects will be caused by the state of the game. Step on a flaming sphere, or just kinda casually stand around in direct contact with it? ***On fire***. It wasn't written in the rules because nobody in 2000 anticipated the new fad that "if it's not explicitly covered by a rule, it doesn't happen". They didn't anticipate needing a rule that says, "When touching a fire, you take normal damage."

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I'm not arguing on that (which is point 1 in my comment). I'm arguing on how to reconcile the application of 1) and the non-application of 2)

Comment: Ah. The sphere is a "yielding, spongy texture". It's designed to not be able to push or impede.

Comment: I would argue that the strict RAW is for no damage to be done unless the move-eq is spent. I would also argue that the RAW in this case is both stupid, and against the apparent intent of the spell, and would rule that it deals damage as described in this answer.