# How does a Flaming Sphere's movement work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, movement

Regarding [Flaming Sphere](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flaming-sphere):

The sphere does damage when it occupies the same space as a creature.  When I move it into a creature's space to attack, the sphere stops moving for the round.  If the creature and sphere don't move, is this attack automatic on my next round, and is the sphere stuck in the same space as the creature until the creature moves?

If I am able to move the sphere out of the space occupied by the creature, does it not do damage to that creature again until it moves back into that creatures space?

Does the sphere move only in a straight line, or can I have it move in a circle (North 5 feet, East 5 feet, South 5 feet, West 5 feet, North 5 feet, South 5 feet)?

Does directing the sphere to move provoke an attack of opportunity?

Can a caster have two spheres at the same time, using two move actions to direct them both during a round?  If so, can both spheres attack a single target?

Comment: related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28495/does-flaming-sphere-always-need-a-move-action-to-attack?rq=1

Comment: @Drunken_Guy thanks, I actually meant to include that in the question.  While clearly the sphere will stay put if I don't use a move action to direct it, the comments to the answer there don't clearly indicate whether the sphere is stripped of that ability automatically.  Since at the beginning of my round the sphere is already in contact with the opponent, I suspect that I lose control of that sphere and it does damage to that target until the target moves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, A caster can have more than one in effect at the same time.

There are no limits to the amount of spells you can have active at any given time unless a spell says otherwise, buffs are subject to stacking penalties, but any spell cast will durate when it reaches the end of its duration.

### Yes, A caster can take a double move ( Two move actions ) to control two spheres in one round

You get three actions in a round, a Standard action, a Move action, and a Swift action. A standard action can be used to make two move actions in a round ( A double move ) so that you can control more than one Flaming sphere per round. However doing so gives up your cast for that round.

### No, Directing the sphere to move does not provoke an attack of opportunity

From: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Direct-or-Redirect-a-Spell

> Direct or Redirect a Spell
>
> Some spells allow you to redirect the effect to new targets or areas after you cast the spell. Redirecting a spell requires a move action and does not provoke attacks of opportunity or require concentration.

### Yes, The sphere deals damage upon entering an enemy space on your initiative count, and it must be moved in a straight line.

The spell states the following:

> A burning globe of fire rolls in **whichever direction you point** and burns those it strikes. It moves 30 feet per round. As part of this movement, it can ascend or jump up to 30 feet to strike a target. If it enters a space with a creature, it stops moving for the round and deals 3d6 points of fire damage to that creature, though a successful Reflex save negates that damage. A flaming sphere rolls over barriers less than 4 feet tall.

Emphasis mine. Since the sphere moves in whichever direction you point, you cannot direct its movement other than pointing to an enemy, which causes the sphere to roll towards said target.

Also, the sphere deals damage when it moves into an enemy's square on your turn, upon which its movement halts. It remains in their square dealing damage if they don't move during their round on your initiative count every turn during its duration. You can choose to move it into the enemy again on your initiative count, upon which it will then cause its damage again.

However it should be noted that Reflex *negates*, so spell-wise the spell [Scorching Ray](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/scorchingRay.html#scorching-ray) is a better alternative against enemies that don't have poor reflex saves.

Comment: What about the timing of damage when moving in/out of a creature's space, or the bit about straight-line movement?

Comment: Because the ball o' fire is directed by pointing, it has to move straight to the location it's pointed towards.

Answer (score 0):

Sandwich's strictest reading possible seems to be taking one liberty that isn't in the spell text.

Text says it only damages when it enters a square. So by a strict reading, you can't make a flaming sphere damage the same enemy two turns in a row if they didn't move out of its square.

The only counter-argument to this is the text saying it "sits in the same square burning/crackling (aggressive thundercloud)". But that doesn't explicitly say it's doing damage. It's just flaming or crackling or whatever.

But our group ruled that you can use your move action to make it exit and re-enter that creature's space in on movement.

Comment: "The sphere moves as long as you actively direct it (a move action for you); otherwise, it merely **stays at rest and burns**." While it does not say there it deals damage, this matches the text for entering a space which says "A burning globe of fire rolls in whichever direction you point and **burns those it strikes**.", which then is detailed as "If it enters a space with a creature, it **stops moving for the round and deals 3d6 points of fire damage**". Considering it burns in either case and does deal damage by not moving, it's at least *probable* that it will deal repeat damage.